# Loading hi-lock patterns from .emacs or custom .el file

Tags: init-file, hi-lock

I'm trying to add syntax highlighting to specific file extensions (for example .foo).
I can't have the Hi-lock patterns in the source code because I shouldn't be committing them.
Is there a way of loading my hi-lock patterns from my .emacs or from a custom .el file when I open a .foo file?

This is my code in my .emacs file:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.foo\\'" . hi-lock-mode))

(defun fooInit ()
 (("!" (0 (quote all-the-icons-dgreen) prepend)))
 (("! .*$" (0 (quote all-the-icons-dgreen) prepend)))
 (("!\\*.*$" (0 (quote all-the-icons-dgreen) prepend)))
 (("!-.*$" (0 (quote all-the-icons-dgreen) prepend)))
 )

(add-hook 'hi-lock-mode-hook 'fooInit)
```

I also tried

```lisp
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.foo\\'" . hi-lock-mode))

(defun fooInit()
Hi-lock: (("!" (0 (quote all-the-icons-dgreen) prepend)))
Hi-lock: (("! .*$" (0 (quote all-the-icons-dgreen) prepend)))
Hi-lock: (("!\\*.*$" (0 (quote all-the-icons-dgreen) prepend)))
Hi-lock: (("!-.*$" (0 (quote all-the-icons-dgreen) prepend)))
)

(add-hook 'hi-lock-mode-hook 'fooInit)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.foo\\'" . hi-lock-mode))

(defun fooInit ()
  (highlight-regexp "!"       'all-the-icons-dgreen)
  (highlight-regexp "! .*$"   'all-the-icons-dgreen)
  (highlight-regexp "!\\*.*$" 'all-the-icons-dgreen)
  (highlight-regexp "!-.*$"   'all-the-icons-dgreen))

(add-hook 'hi-lock-mode-hook 'fooInit)
```

If it does, and you're interested in expanding your Elisp skillset, then to optimise this you might combine those four patterns into a single one using `"\\|"`, or you might put the four patterns in a list and call `highlight-regexp` in a loop. The really advanced approach is to use `mapc`, but don't bother with that until you're ready and curious; just be aware that something called `mapc` exists.

Comment: Thank you very much! That solved it! Yes I'm very much interested in expanding my Elisp knowledge, I shall try that out as well. Would you also by any chance know how to make it interactive highlight when I edit?